# Grouping of methods

Tags: c#, clean-code, methods

We have multiple pages searching for users, each site having different search parameters. Sometimes, we have 2 parameters, sometimes 4 and most of these parameters overlap. So we have kind of (simplified) this code:

```
SearchUser()
{
    // Get values from somewhere
    Service.SearchActiveUser(firstname, lastname);
}
SearchUserSomewhereElse()
{
    // Get values from somewhere
    Service.SearchUser(lastname, id);
}

// some other layer
SearchActiveUser(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    var users = from user in allusers
                where user.IsActive == true
                select user;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname))
        users = users.Where(user => user.Firstname == firstname);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
        users = users.Where(user => user.Lastname == lastname);

    return users
}

SearchUser(string lastname, int? id)
{
    var users = from user in allusers
                select user;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname))
        users = users.Where(user => user.Lastname== lastname);
    if (id.HasValue)
        users = users.Where(user => user.Id == id);

    return users;
}
```

Now, we have another search for some other data where we got one giant search value object (30+ search properties) and one method that filters it all.
Applying this to the user situation, it'd look like this:

```
SearchUser()
{
    // Get values from somewhere
    var searchVO = new UserSearchVO { Firstname = firstname, Lastname = lastname, IsActive = true };
    Service.SearchUser(searchVO);
}
SearchUserSomewhereElse()
{
    // Get values from somewhere
    var searchVO = new UserSearchVO { Lastname = lastname, Id = id };
    Service.SearchUser(searchVO);
}

// some other layer
SearchUser(UserSearchVO searchVO)
{
    var users = from user in allusers
                select user;

    if (searchVO.IsActive.HasValue)
        users = users.Where(user => user.IsActive == searchVO.IsActive);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVO.Firstname))
        users = users.Where(user => user.Firstname == searchVO.Firstname);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVO.Lastname))
        users = users.Where(user => user.Lastname == searchVO.Lastname);
    if (searchVO.Id.HasValue)
        users = users.Where(user => user.Id == searchVO.Id);
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchVO.SomeFutureValue))
        users = users.Where(user => user.SomeFutureValue == searchVO.SomeFutureValue);

    return users;
}
```

I understand that the first approach is the starting approach, I don't use a search object if I don't need one with 2 params. But I feel like violating some principles of clean code with the latter approach.

Which principles of clean code do I violate using the second approach and is there another clean way of keeping it readable while not having 5000 different methods to filter 1 object?

Comment: I see second solution as reasonably clear and understandable.

Comment: @Euphoric: this "clean and understandable" code makes it easy to overlook errors - as the OP already did (trivia: did you find the "copy-paste bug"?). Moreover, the OP mentioned 30+ attributes, so this is becoming a DRY violation.

Comment: @DocBrown Not saying you shouldn't have automated test for every property. And if the User has 30+ properties, it is problem with the User itself, not how it is filtered.

Comment: @Euphoric: The User has many properties like hair color, skin tone, height, eye color, and so on. What might be the problem here? Edited question to kill copy-paste-bugs.

Comment: With so many properties, I might recommend some kind of code generation. Both for the entity itself and for query filter parameter object and it's implementation.

Comment: I guess you could also decorate the properties inside `UserSearchVO` with a custom attribute that defines the corresponding property in your user object. Then you could fetch all assigned and decorated props via reflection and dynamically build your linq query without hard coding every if-statement.

Comment: @MarcelKirsche It is still necessary to create either method with all the parameters or an object with all the properties by which it is possible to filter.

Comment: @Euphoric Yes, but you would not have to maintain your list of if-statements. In order to implement a new search property, you'd simply add the property to your search value object together with the attribute in a declarative way. Otherwise you'd need to add the new property anyways and you'd also have to add another if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed you don't want to change the existing `User` object significantly, you could use reflection to

- iterate over the properties of `UserSearchVO`
- check for the equally named properties of `User`
- implement a generic comparison of those properties for the data types required

This approach can be extended by providing custom attributes to the properties of `UserSearchVO` to declare how the comparison shall be done (like mentioned in a comment by @MarcelKirsche).

This is surely overkill for 5 properties, but if you have really more than 30, it may be worth the effort.

Answer (score 4):

I find this much more readable:

```
// some other layer
SearchUser(UserSearchVO searchVO)
{
    var users = from user in allusers
                select user;

    users = MatchIsActive(users, searchVO);
    users = MatchFirstname(users, searchVO);
    users = MatchLastname(users, searchVO);
    users = MatchId(users, searchVO);
    users = MatchSomeFutureValue(users, searchVO);

    return users;
}
```

Yes it creates a bit more work behind the scenes but it's behind the scenes where it belongs. Please don't show me everything going on all at once. These functions could be methods on `UserSearchVO`.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a builder pattern:

```cs
var users = SearchUserWhich
  .IsActive()
  .FirstNameIs('Joe')
  .LastNameIs('Random')
  .Fetch();
```

Now you can combine the filters internally the way you want until you call `.Fetch`.

Basically you are wrapping SQL in a (limited) DSL because you're not using a nice SQL DSL for whatever reason (e.g. you do need that limitation, or you want joins handled automatically, etc).

Answer (score 1):

**UserSearchVO is just a search expression**

Your `UserSearchVO` object represents a search expression. So it seems reasonable that the `UserSearchVO` class would know how to convert itself into an `Expression<Func<User,bool>>`, which you could then provide to the `Where` clause. A simple example might look like this (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21801867/2791540)):

```
class UserSearchVO
{
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public bool? Firstname { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<User, bool>> ToExpression()
    {
        var type = typeof(User);
        List<Expression> expressions = new List<Expression>();
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

        if (IsActive.HasValue)
        {
            var expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, type.GetProperty("IsActive")), Expression.Constant(IsActive.Value));
            expressions.Add(expression);
        }
        if (Firstname.HasValue)
        {
            var expression = Expression.Equal(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, type.GetProperty("Firstname")), Expression.Constant(IsActive.Value));
            expressions.Add(expression);
        }

        //Put other properties (e.g. Lastname) here

        Expression final = expressions.First();
        foreach (var expression in expressions.Skip(1))
        {
            final = Expression.And(final, expression);
        }

        Expression<Func<User, bool>> predicate =
            (Expression<Func<User, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(final, parameter);

        return predicate;
    }
}
```

Now in your search method you can just do this:

```
SearchUser(UserSearchVO searchVO)
{
    var users = from user in allusers
                select user;
    users = users.Where(searchVO.ToExpression());
    return users;
}
```

...which seems pretty crystal clear to me, and maintains encapsulation.

For your other methods you can leverage the first one, e.g.

```
SearchActiveUser(string firstname, string lastname)
{
    var search = new UserSearchVO
    {
        IsActive = true, 
        Firstname = firstname, 
        LastName = lastname
    };

    return SearchUser(search);
}
```